# How do I call multiple parameters with multiple arguments on one line in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, powershell-2.0

I have a script where I want to call multiple parameters, which may take multiple arguments, at the same time with the format:

```
.\MyScript.ps1 -q <int> --args <hostval1> <hostval2> ... <hostvaln>
```

Right now, I have other parameters besides "q", but they do not need the "--args" parameter. I currently can't figure out how to implement "--args", because I currently have my parameters defined like so:

```
param(
    [Alias('c')]
    [string]$csv,
    [Alias('h')]
    [switch]$help,
    [Alias('f')]
    [switch]$fields,
    [Alias('s')]
    [string]$sql,
    [Alias('q')]
    [int]$query
)
```

I know I could run it like this to get hostvalues, but it would require a dash:

```
.\MyScript.ps1 -q 1 -hostval1 -hostval3 -hostval4
```

This makes

```
$args[0] = -hostval1
$args[1] = -hostval3
$args[2] = -hostval4
```

Is there any way to make a "secondary" parameter (e.g. --args) that can only be called with "-q", and accepts multiple values separated by spaces? I could create another parameter, but this would allow it to accidentally be called without the "-q" parameter, and also requires commas between arguments:

```
[string[]]$hostvals
```

Is what I'm looking to do possible in powershell? Does anyone have any ideas of what I could do?

Comment: Can't you just create a parameter `[string[]]$hostvals` and use that to input the values. If you want to use it only when `$query` is set, use this `if ($query) { "Query parameter present"..  run code that uses $hostvals } else { run code that doesn't use $hostvals }`

Comment: Is there any way to modify the get-help output? Currently it displays this "MyScript.ps1 [[-csv] <String>] [[-sql] <String>] [[-query] <Int32>] [[-arg] <String[]>] [-help] [-fields]"

Comment: Do you want to edit that syntax or provide additional information with definitions of paramters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with parametersetname:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Q")]

param(    
    [Alias('c')]
    [string]$csv,   
    [Alias('h')]
    [switch]$help,    
    [Alias('f')]
    [switch]$fields,    
    [Alias('s')]
    [string]$sql,   
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Q", mandatory=$true)] 
    [Alias('q')]
    [int]$query,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Q")] 
    [object[]]$arg        
)
```

In this way you can't call function using only `-arg` parameter, you need call `-query` also.

`$arg` accept an array, you can input your hostvals separed by commas. If you want values separed by spaces you can declare `[string]$arg` and pass value in quotes, but you need to add some logic ( `split` on spaces and so o on...) to make input usefull inside the script.

For adding custom help to your scripts read here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/07/hey-scripting-guy-january-7-2010.aspx